# What programming language does Sony's PhyreEngine use?

Tags: playstation3

I'm looking into developing a title for the next PlayStation (to be unveiled on Feb 20th) and PSVita to be distributed on the PlayStation Network. I know how to get in contact with Sony and all, but I haven't submitted my application yet (even though I have a pretty good portfolio) and I was hoping to use Sony's own PhyreEngine for development of the game.

I was wondering if any of you guys knew what programming language the engine uses or is based on? As I want to be well prepared for production of the game. Also, if there's anyone who reads this and has developed a PSN game before, do you have a rough outline of how much it'd cost? (Dev Kits, SDKs, licenses etc.)

Thanks

Harry

Comment: I guess you should ask this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

PhyreEngine itself is written in C++. The tools are primarily C#.

Can't tell you anything about costs in general, you'd have to get in touch through official channels for that info. PhyreEngine itself is free to any licensed developer though, it's just part of the SDK.

(disclosure - PhyreEngine is my project)

Answer (score 0):

PhyreEngine is based on C++, with a possibility of a few low level C libraries.

This information is from a post in this forum: http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/181890-What-runs-on-a-PS3/page2, about halfway down the page. A poster asked the same questions you did.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not 100% this is purely accurate, but from scanning several forums, C++ seems to be the accepted language. I highly recommend looking into C++ if you haven't all ready, and to build a strong foundation on object-oriented programming concepts if its an area you do not have much experience in. Best of luck!

Comment: And yeah, I've done a small bit of Objective-C, so I have a rough idea of Object-Oriented programming. This is great, and good luck with whatever you're working on right now :)